Optimizing Apex Trigger Code on Opportunity
I've built a few custom Salesforce flows on the Opportunity object to automate processes, however I keep running into the reoccurring issue of the SOQL queries timing out and my flows failing the debug due to this trigger code on the Opportunity object, built by the previous developers.
"This error occurred: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: trgOpportunity: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101."
I'm struggling to understand exactly how to optimize this trigger to avoid SOQL timeout, however I only know basic apex code and am unsure if I'm interpreting this trigger in it's entirety.
From my interpretation, I believe this trigger "locks in" the List Price of the related  Opportunity Product record when the Opp stage is changed to Closed Won. This is so that the List Price does not change if the Org exchange rate is updated, but only for Opportunities which are Closed Won. We still need this functionality, however I want to deploy my flows.
trigger trgOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update) {
if(Trigger.isBefore)
{
    if(Trigger.IsInsert)
    {
        OpportunityController.populateCreateOpportunityName(Trigger.New);
    }
    else if(Trigger.IsUpdate)
    {
        OpportunityController.populateUpdateOpportunityName(Trigger.NewMap, Trigger.OldMap);
    }
}

if(Trigger.isAfter)
{
    if(Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        system.debug('IN UPDATE');
        try
        {
            List<OpportunityLineItem> updateList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
            For(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
            {
                Id oppId = opp.Id;
                
                List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLineItemList = [SELECT Id,Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId =: oppId];
                if(oppLineItemList.size() > 0){
                    Set<Id> oppLineItemIdSet = new Set<Id>();
                    Set<Id> productIdSet = new Set<Id>();
                    for(OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem : oppLineItemList)
                    {
                        oppLineItemIdSet.add(oppLineItem.Id);
                        productIdSet.add(oppLineItem.Product2Id);
                    }
                    system.debug('oppLineItemIdSet: '+oppLineItemIdSet);
                    system.debug('productIdSet: '+productIdSet);
                    
                    List<Product2> ProductList = [SELECT Id,USD_Related__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN: productIdSet];
                    List<Product2> relateProductList = [SELECT Id,Nett_Price__c,Commission_Amount__c,AUD_Product__c,CurrencyIsoCode FROM Product2 WHERE AUD_Product__c IN: productIdSet];
                    system.debug('ProductList: '+ProductList);
                    system.debug('relateProductList: '+relateProductList);
                    
                    String stage = opp.StageName;
                    
                    
                    system.debug('stage: '+stage);
                    
                    if(stage == 'Closed Won')
                    {
                        for(OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem : oppLineItemList){
                            for(Product2 product : ProductList){
                                for(Product2 relateProduct : relateProductList){
                                    if(oppLineItem.Product2Id == product.Id && product.USD_Related__c == TRUE && relateProduct.AUD_Product__c == product.Id){
                                        
                                        system.debug('IF-------------------------------------');
                                        system.debug('oppLineItem Product ID: '+oppLineItem.Product2Id);
                                        system.debug('Product ID: '+product.Id);
                                        system.debug('USD Related: '+product.USD_Related__c);
                                        system.debug('P2 lookup P1: '+relateProduct.AUD_Product__c);
                                        
                                        String relateProductCurrency = relateProduct.CurrencyIsoCode;
                                        String opportunityCurrency = opp.CurrencyIsoCode;
                                        
                                        CurrencyType curType = [SELECT Id, IsoCode, ConversionRate FROM CurrencyType WHERE IsoCode = 'USD'];
                                        
                                        oppLineItem.USD_NET_PRICE__c = 'USD '+String.valueOf(relateProduct.Nett_Price__c.setScale(2));
                                        oppLineItem.USD_Comm_Amount__c = 'USD '+String.valueOf(relateProduct.Commission_Amount__c.setScale(2));
                                        //oppLineItem.USD_NET_PRICE_Updated__c = True;
                                        updateList.add(oppLineItem);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    /*else
                                    {
                                        system.debug('ELSE-------------------------------------');
                                        system.debug('oppLineItem Product ID: '+oppLineItem.Product2Id);
                                        system.debug('Product ID: '+product.Id);
                                        system.debug('USD Related: '+product.USD_Related__c);
                                        system.debug('P2 lookup P1: '+relateProduct.AUD_Product__c);
                                    }*/
                                }   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        system.debug('Stage is not Closed Won.');
                    } 
                }
                else{
                    system.debug('Opportunity not have Opportunity Product.');
                }
            }
            
            if(updateList.size() > 0)
            {
                system.debug('updateList: '+updateList);
                update updateList;
            }
        }
        Catch(exception ex)
        {
            system.debug('Error: '+ex.getMessage());
            system.debug('Line: '+String.valueOf(ex.getLineNumber()));
        }
    }
}

Any thoughts here would be greatly appreciated!

The error is caused by running multiple SOQL queries inside a for loop which violates the salesforce governor limits. You can read this documentation to follow all the best practices of writing apex: https://developer.salesforce.com/ja/wiki/apex_code_best_practices

Notice the ProductList and relateProductList variables are initialized from a query in the loop over oppLineItemList, which is itself queried in a loop over the opportunities. This code simply does not follow bulkification at all. (There's a future non-bulkified query of curType.)
